# Farm backup stuck on Step 1

Tags: error, backup, farm

Ours is Multi server (2 WFE and 2 APP) SP 2016 Env.

As usual when we am trying to start backup of the entire farm, it remains on Step 1.
[image]

We checked the ULS and found request has timeout
[image]

However if we try to select only WSPs or other smaller component It moves to Step 2. Not able to make out what is going wrong today. We have been backing up the farm through C.A. for past many months.

When trying to Backup using PowerShell

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory "\\servername\test backup" -BackupMethod Full -Verbose
```

[image]

Waited for 20 mins. as there where no logs checked the Resource utilization.
[image]

[image]

There is Free Disk Space is 50 GB, whereas the backup always ranges between 28 GB.

Comment: You powershell screen is freeze, it is in pause conditoon... courser size giving me hint....either press enter after selecting the powershell window or open a new window with run as admin and try again.

Answer (score 1):

**Some points to note and check,**

- If the farm size (content databases, configuration databases) is large, it normally will take a long time and maybe lead to **timeout error** compared to backup a small piece from your farm like WSP.
- Make sure that the SP servers resources are not consumed during the backup operation, it's preferred to take a backup out working hour.
- Try to perform the full fam backup operation using PowerShell, and check the behavior, also please check [Back up farms in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/back-up-a-farm)

  ```
  Backup-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -BackupMethod {Full | Differential} [-Verbose]
  ```
- Make sure you have sufficient disk space in the backup directory.
- Make sure the backup directory is excluded from the Antivirus.
- Make sure the backup RAID storage is
- Check the Config database log, if it rapidly growth try to handle it as mentioned at  [THE RAPID GROWTH OF THE SHAREPOINT CONFIG DATABASE TRANSACTION LOG (FULL).](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/26/the-transaction-log-for-database-sharepoint_config-is-full-due-to-log_backup/)

Comment: Hi Mohamed,
Have updated the ticket with comments on your points.

Comment: Hi Mohamed,
Have updated the ticket with comments on your points with pictures.